# How To Read Outlook Emails From Different Accounts in Outlook From Specific Folders?

Tags: python, outlook, automation, com

I am trying to read emails from only specific accounts logged into my outlook. Let's say I have Accounts 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & suppose they all have custom folders: Folder 1, Folder 2, Folder 3. I want to read all the emails from Folder 1, 2 & 3 only from Accounts 1, 3 & 5.

My code seems to be okay, but my problem is that I really cannot seem to figure out how to choose the account I want to read from, so my code is only reading the one default account. I need to know how to specify which account to read from.

```py
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

folders = ["Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3"]

for folder in folders:
    messages = inbox.Folders(folder).Items
    for msg in messages:
        print(msg.Subject)
```

etc...

// EDIT //

To do this, I have done the following:

```py
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

stores = outlook.Stores # Storing the different outlook profiles

# Loop through each outlook profile
for store in stores:
    if "Account 1" in store.DisplayName or "Account 3" in store.DisplayName or "Account 5" in store.DisplayName: 
        inbox = store.GetDefaultFolder(6) # Get Inbox

        folders = ["Folder 1", "Folder 2", "Folder 3"]

        for folder in folders:
            messages = inbox.Folders(folder).Items
            for msg in messages:
                print(msg.Subject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`, loop through the stores in the `Namespace.Stores` collection and for each `Store` object call `Store.GetDefaultFolder`.

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way to Read Outlook Emails From Different Accounts in Outlook From Specific Folders:

```
import win32com.client

myEmailAccount = "my-email-address@outlook.com"
folderName = "myFolder"

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
store = outlook.Stores(myEmailAccount)
inbox = store.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[folderName]

messages = inbox.Items
for msg in messages:
    print(msg.Subject)
```